# Spring send jsp:param to the jsp from the controller

Tags: spring

So i have this command to call a jsp:

```
<jsp:include page="some.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="myValue" value="false" />
</jsp:include>
```

Cool. Now if I use that value in the jsp it's like this:

```
<c:if test="${param.myValue != 'false'}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

Ok. How do I send this to the jsp from a spring controller?

```
model.addAttribute("myValue",false);
return new ModelAndView("some", model);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find out how to do this.
In the end I just had

```
model.put("someWord", false);
```

and in the jsp

```
<c:if test="${param.myValue != null}">
    <c:set var="someWord" val="${param.myValue}"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${someWord != 'false'}">
    ...
</c:if>
```